# Align Text Dynamically - JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

How to alter the size of text field dynamically based on the data that is coming in html page?

User may enter data blindly. In that case report are getting messed up. Can anyone please figure out how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can not extend textfield in horizontal side. But if you want to print all data you should set srtetchOverflow property as true for that textfield.

Comment: I already did that..But it ain't working.Is there any other way to change the size of text field dynamically based on the size of content that is coming in html view.?

Comment: Post your jrxml code for more understanding...

Comment: @user1791574 : here is the link for jrxml code. I was not able to paste the whole code here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8oe6ywwpi3b0md/Demo.jrxml